# Apache Cassandra "no viable alternative at input 'OR' "

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

My table looks like :

```
CREATE TABLE prod_cust (
    pid bigint,
    cid bigint,
    effective_date date,
    expiry_date date,
    PRIMARY KEY ((pid, cid))
);
```

My below query is giving no viable alternative at input 'OR' error

```
SELECT * FROM prod_cust 
where 
pid=101 and cid=201 
OR 
pid=102 and cid=202;
```

Does Cassandra not support OR operator if not, Is there any alternate way to achieve my result.

Comment: Syntax aside, the condition is ambiguous. Do you mean `(pid=101 and cid=201) OR (pid=102 and cid=202)`? Or do you mean `id=101 and (cid=201 OR pid=102) and cid=202`? Chances are you want the former. When *and* and *or* are used flatly in composite conditions like that, you know it's likely to be buggy.

Comment: The former one, I tried with that too, it gives error:
mismatched input 'and' expecting ')' (... where (pid = 101 [and] cid...)

Comment: @ernest_k The same condition works in my RDBMS table, since I am migrating to cassandra, I wanted the same behavior here as well. Is there any workaround.

Comment: With the partition key being a composite of 2 values, there is potential that they could be combined into a single value - at which point OR because possible via IN. All access to that table (outside of allow filtering) would be with both PID and CID, so if they can be combined into a single value - you have an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CQL does not support the `OR` operator.  Sometimes you can get around that by using `IN`.  But even `IN` won't let you do what you're attempting.

I see two options:

- Submit each side of your `OR` as individual queries.
- Restructure the table to better-suit what you're trying to do.  Doing a "port-over" from a RDBMS to Cassandra almost never works as intended.